# How to customize my Laravel email verification message

Tags: php, laravel, email

during the conception of my web site using **laravel 7** I found some troubles when I wanted to customize my laravel customize my Laravel email verification message.
first, I went to this file "C:\xampp\htdocs\clinique_juridique\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php",then i translate the sentences that are there .
Here I met two issues, the first one some sentences are not in VerifyEmail.php so I couldn't translate them the second one, I didn't know how to change the style of the message, of course, also I didn't know how to include the logo of my website.
thank you in advance.

Comment: I strongly advise againt editing any files in the `vendor` folder, next time you update your dependencies your changes will most likely be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

So I think you're asking about this specific part of the code (took from Laravel 8 vendor code):

```
 /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }
```

First, you may use this class `VerifyEmail` and method `toMail` to send this confirmation email to your client, but if you look closer, you can identify that this function is using the `Lang` class, which can be found at [Laravel Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization).

Otherwise, if you want to make it more complex you can create your own class MyVerifyEmail which extends VerifyEmail and recreate toMail method to serve your needs, but I can't think of a scenario where you do this.

Second, if you want to include some personalized style of your mail, try creating a [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#configuring-the-view), with this approach you can use a custom view (of course including a logo).

And finally, I encourage to do not to modify the vendor's directory, because it stores all the libraries that laravel needs to work properly. Instead, extend any class which you may want to modify.